# Azure Functions v4 - Filter out Logs using host.json settings?

Tags: c#, logging, azure-functions

I have an Azure Functions v4 Isolated Worker project that is spitting out a heap of log messages when my function has any interaction with the Azure SDK libraries (blob storage, table storage etc). The log messages seem to relate to the `Azure.Identity` package but I cant figure out how to only log `Warning` level log messages and above?

These are the kind of log messages I would like to exclude (they are all logged as `Information` level):

```
[2023-01-01T01:52:09.967Z] DefaultAzureCredential.GetToken invoked. Scopes: [ https://storage.azure.com/.default ] ParentRequestId: dca56710-cad0-4f36-ac49-a11ffbe5f5e1
[2023-01-01T01:52:09.974Z] EnvironmentCredential.GetToken invoked. Scopes: [ https://storage.azure.com/.default ] ParentRequestId: dca56710-cad0-4f36-ac49-a11ffbe5f5e1
[2023-01-01T01:52:09.976Z] EnvironmentCredential.GetToken was unable to retrieve an access token. Scopes: [ https://storage.azure.com/.default ] ParentRequestId: dca56710-cad0-4f36-ac49-a11ffbe5f5e1 Exception: Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException (0x80131500): EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot
[2023-01-01T01:52:09.981Z] ManagedIdentityCredential.GetToken invoked. Scopes: [ https://storage.azure.com/.default ] ParentRequestId: dca56710-cad0-4f36-ac49-a11ffbe5f5e1
[2023-01-01T01:52:10.130Z] False MSAL 4.46.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 6.0.12 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19044 [2023-01-01 01:52:10Z - 148f7c4b-dab8-4f91-9575-8fed36cf4950] MSAL MSAL.NetCore with assembly version '4.46.0.0'. CorrelationId(148f7c4b-dab8-4f91-9575-8fed36cf4950)
[2023-01-01T01:52:10.137Z] False MSAL 4.46.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 6.0.12 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19044 [2023-01-01 01:52:10Z - 148f7c4b-dab8-4f91-9575-8fed36cf4950] === AcquireTokenForClientParameters ===
[2023-01-01T01:52:10.138Z] SendX5C: False
[2023-01-01T01:52:10.139Z] ForceRefresh: False
[2023-01-01T01:52:10.139Z]
[2023-01-01T01:52:10.141Z] False MSAL 4.46.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 6.0.12 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19044 [2023-01-01 01:52:10Z - 148f7c4b-dab8-4f91-9575-8fed36cf4950]
[2023-01-01T01:52:10.142Z] False MSAL 4.46.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 6.0.12 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19044 [2023-01-01 01:52:10Z - 148f7c4b-dab8-4f91-9575-8fed36cf4950] === Token Acquisition (ClientCredentialRequest) started:
         Scopes: https://storage.azure.com/.default
        Authority Host: login.microsoftonline.com
```

And I have this set up in my `host.json` file but it seems to have NO effect:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "Azure": "Warning",
      "Azure.Core": "Warning",
      "Azure.Data.Tables": "Warning",
      "Azure.Identity": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Identity": "Warning"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that if I set a `"default": "Warning"` in the `logging:logLevel` block then it does work but I cant get it to work for a specific log category.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken Sample Http Trigger and did experiment with the Log Levels related to "Warning" level logs.

When I define the Function attribute to Warning/Information level, then it gave me the Function Level user defined Warning Logs:

[image]

To get the Warning Level Logs for the Packages/Libraries used in the Function Level Code,

```
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "None",
      "Function": "Information",
      "Host": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs": "Information"
    },
```

[image]

If any warnings are observed, then it will show the logs. Otherwise, it will show the logs with value null with the related defined attributes like `Microsoft.Azure.*`

The above code taken from this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-categories) of Azure Functions Monitoring Log level categories which states that

> Exceptions are logged at the `Error` level. The runtime also creates `Warning` level logs

and the default value **`Warning`** is set to all the function classes, telemetry categories, along with the Worker Level including Microsoft.

In the Same Document of this [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#solutions-with-high-volume-of-telemetry), Without setting the default log level to error or **`warning`** or **`information`**, you will not get much information regarding any telemetry data or in the production environment, you have to define the log level explicitly for the specific function `Function.Function_Name`  with the Information value or **`Error`**/**`Warning`** for bringing up the system generated logs instead of user defined logs in the Function Code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately none of those suggestions helped. My logLevel specific settings are still not working